# What can I do when there are two variables in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Here are some C code:

```
    void func(int s,int t)
    {
      int i,j;
      int array[10][10];
      for(i=s,j=t;i>0 && j>0;i--,j--)
        array[i][j]=5;
    }
```

How can I do that in Python?

Comment: Why not just `for i in range(3): j = i + 5 ...`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe   But sometimes the value of i and j are uncertain.

Comment: Not in this case, they aren't. Do you mean in general?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  May be my question is not clear,I have modified my question.

Comment: It would appear that you can still rewrite that example using the technique in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you could do something like:

```
for i, j in zip(range(3), range(5, 8)):
    ...
```

where:

```
>>> range(3)
[0, 1, 2]
>>> range(5, 8)
[5, 6, 7]
>>> zip(range(3), range(5, 8))
[(0, 5), (1, 6), (2, 7)]
```

See the documentation on [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range). If you're using Python 2.x and there will be lots of values, using [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) and [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) could be more efficient.